# Force SED to jump/reset to first line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

It is known that **sed** is used to parse a file line by line.
Is there a way to make it jump once again to the first line, once it reaches the last line for example ?

## Update

Take this example:
if we encounter **option: [opt]**, we should remove this line, and place **opt** in front of each **line1:** token

#### Input file

```
line
line
line1:
line
option: -a
line
```

#### Expected output file

```
line
line
line1: -a
line
line
```

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: I think it can not do with only sed.

Comment: It is not possible. You can only like specify the same file for sed as argument twice. Most probably this is XY question, this is not needed to solve the problem you are having. You can store the whole file in hold space anyway, so you could parse it all. In your example, if you encounter `line1:`, put all the lines in hold space until you get `option:` line, then add `line1: -a` to hold space and then just print the hold space and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's#^option:(.*)#/^line1:/s/$/\1/;/^&/d#p' file | sed -f - file
```

Create a sed script by processing the original file and building a substituion and a delete command. Then apply the sed script to the original file.

Comment: Amazingly it works !
However, I do not understand the meaning of "-f - file". It is clearly posix-specific.
What does this option mean ? Why it does not work if I use only "-f file" ?

Comment: @MahmoudMasmoudi the `-f -` option means take the commands for sed from a file, in this case `-` which is another name for `/dev/stdin` the result of the previous pipe `|`. If you send the results of the first invocation of sed to a file you can replace `-` with that files name. Then there is no need for the pipe and it can be replaced by a `;` to end the previous command.

Comment: Creating a script file by substitution is very clever !
Thank you @potong for this tip ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to process the lines in reverse here.

You can use `tac` to reverse the file, then use the hold space more conventionally:

`tac file | sed '/option/{s/.*://;h;d};/line1:/{G;s/\n//}' | tac`

This uses `h` to hold the option flag.  `d` to delete that line.

`G` appends the hold space to each `line1` line.

Then pipe to `tac` to reverse the order of the lines again.  The two calls to `tac` would be costly if `file` is large.  But this might be more extensible code.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But the order of the `option:` line relatively to `line1` can be different.  
So I don't think that reversing the file could be useful for me.